# What calendar-dependent laws must non-Jews follow?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, calendar

While the calendar is vastly important in Judaism, it seems like it is barely applicable to non-Jews. The ["big seven" Noahide laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah) seem to be perenially applicable; they dictate general rules for life rather than specific holy days or timed rituals. That being said, what calendar-dependent laws does *halacha* dictate that non-Jews must follows? I know of at least one possible example – the prohibition against keeping Shabbat ([מיי' הל' מלכים ומלחמות פ"י הי"א](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e510.htm) , though technically this applies even if the non-Jew observes a Shabbat-like rest on any day of the week).

Comment: Does the karbanot during sukkoth count?

Comment: @avi Are non-Jews actually mechuyav to bring them?

Comment: Well, ask yourself this: Is there any day of the calendar in which the *halakha* allows non-Jews to sin ?